# Azure B2B/SharePoint access for external users

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure

We have two AAD/Office 365 tenants, and I've heard that Azure B2b *might* be what we want, but I'm not currently sure if it is capable of what *exactly* we're looking for.

We have users in tenant A with @domain1.com accounts. It is here that we've built a SharePoint site collection. SharePoint Online specifically.

We would like to grant visitor/view access to all current and new users in tenant B/@domainb.com users so they can view these sites.

Essentially, is there a way to grant anyone with an @domain2.com account automatic access without the email invitation/redemption process? @domain2.com users are also already Microsoft accounts (work/business accounts) and we control this tenant as well.

Then beyond that, is there a way to have this auto-access on a specific site and all of its subsites/pages, but exclude that access to other sites in the same collection? We would want @domain2.com users to have access to only parts of the Site Collection.

Answer (score 1):

No. You either have to use anonymous links which work at the item level or you have to invite the user via email address at the site level (or lower; this would be your exclusionary question).